# Imported OWL files not being used

Tags: java, import, jena, ontology, owl

I have created an OWL file in TURTLE notation from Protege, which uses two imports:

```
owl:imports <http://localhost/imported1.owl> ,
<http://localhost/imported2.owl> .
```

I have loaded this on Jena. When I query the file, I don't get any answer from the imports, but just from the file itself.
For example if I have a class "Person" and I query the model (both with SPARQL or with a reasoner) to find individuals of this class I only get the individuals in my file, but not from the imported files "imported1.owl" and "imported2.owl".

I have read the imported files are loaded by default ([imports processing](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html#compound-ontology-documents-and-imports-processing)) Is there anything else I have to do?

If for example I mix the three files in one instead of using import I get the expected results.

**==== EDIT ====**

Both files (imported1.owl and imported2.owl) are accessible via a Web server (if I type the URL I get the file correctly).

This is the code:

```
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(file);
        if (in == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            ontology.read(in, null, "TURTLE");
        }
        Reasoner owlReasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
        Reasoner reasoner = owlReasoner.bindSchema(ontology);
        InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, ontology);

        String queryString = " PREFIX eg: <http://eg.owl#>"
                + " SELECT ?p WHERE { ?p <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> eg:Person }";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, ontology);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
```

If this code runs against the owl file with the "owl:imports", I get only the Person instances defined in the file itself, but ignoring the instances defined within the imported files.

**==== EDIT 2====**

[irrelevant]

It seems like I am doing something wrong - either the imports are not loaded because of an error in the original .owl file or Jena is only using the base document.

**==== EDIT 3====**

It seems the models are loaded correctly (I have also checked with hasLoadedImport()):

ontology.countSubModels(): 2

So I discarded the imports are not loaded correctly. Somehow then it seems Jena is only using the base document and not the imported ones...

Comment: Please show your code. Hard to debug what might be wrong with it otherwise. Also, it's an obvious question, but you have set up a web server so that http://localhost/imported1.owl resolves, right? What happens if you type that URL into your web browser?

Comment: Thanks Ian Dickinson, I have just updated my question